# How to convert string to datetime using c#

Tags: c#, datetime

When try to convert string value in date-time format some time string variable comes with null value at that time it throws exception invalid format of the sting. 
e.g

```
string abc=//date vale
 datetime dt=new datetime();
 dt=DateTime.Parse(abc);
//if abc comes null it throws exception.
//I can check in this way
if(abc!=null)
{
 dt=DateTime.Parse(abc);
}
```

Comment: `dt=(datetime)abc`? Casting a string to DateTime?! What do you expect to happen, other than of course getting a compile-time error?

Comment: If string is null then it throws exception that invalid string format

Comment: I don't think this will even compile. Are you sure you posted your exact code? And what's the big deal about checking for null?

Comment: Oh no, not only of string is null. This will not even compile my friend.

Comment: Groo and Darin please check it now

Comment: Yeah, I have checked it. This code doesn't compile. By the way there's no such type as `datetime` in .NET. I guess you meant `DateTime`.

Comment: My question was not about parsing actually i want to know better approach if string is null but people are answer about parsing

Comment: Hi @user1387147, please be careful not to change the original code on which the answers below are based. It's not good for the future usefulness of this question.

Comment: @user1387147 The task parsing encompasses the issue of the string being null.

Comment: We are talking about *parsing* because this is the correct notion used when you want to convert a string to a DateTime instance: by parsing it.

Comment: @FishBasketGordo i just change my question because people start comment about parsing rather then my original question.

Comment: @FishBasketGordo: I believe OP made a typo with casting (s/he was using `DateTime.Parse` from the beginning). The question seems to be something like "Strings are null, but for some reason I don't want to check for null".

Comment: @Groo I see now. Thanks for clearing that up. Not a very well-worded question unfortunately.

Comment: @user1387147: by "having more then 100 string variable", are you saying that your method contains 100 **different** string variables, being converted into DateTimes sequentially?

Comment: You can always use the good ol' ternary: `DateTime dt = (s != null) ? DateTime.Parse(s) : DateTime.MinValue;`. It's actually slightly less readable, IMHO, but whatever. Seriously, what is the problem with checking for null?

Comment: DateTime.TryParse is the right way to go !

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have a look at `DateTime.TryParse`*<sup>[[MSDN]](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparse.aspx)</sup>*.

**EDIT:**

If you don't want to duplicate this code, put it in a method, perhaps with a nullable return value:

```
public DateTime? ParseDate(string dateString)
{
    DateTime dt;
    if (DateTime.TryParse(dateString, out dt))
    {
        return dt;
    }
    else
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Use the following code.

```
string abc=//date vale
DateTime dt;        
if(DateTime.TryParse(abc, out dt)
{
       // do something
}
```

Comment: `DateTime.Parse` will throw an exception if `abc` is null. The OP was trying to avoid that.

Comment: @FishBasketGordo this is what i want to know. Is there any better approach other then if condition?

Comment: Well `DateTime.TryParse(..)` gives an defualt-value to the out-parameter (dt in this case). So if you can live with that, you could leave out the if...

Comment: *IF* the string can be null, you'll need to use an `if` statement to handle it, or accept the default value, which I think is `DateTime.MinValue` in this case. However, you can put the above code in a method to avoid duplicating it.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`DateTime.TryParse(string s, out DateTime result)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch92fbc1.aspx). This method will try to parse the string into the result and return `true` if it worked / `false` if parsing isn't possible.

```
string abc = //date vale
datetime dt;
bool didItWork = DateTime.TryParse(abc, out dt);
```

Answer (score 5):

You should be using `DateTime.TryParse()` to make sure you avoid the exception.

Answer (score 4):

use this one

```
Convert.ToDateTime();
```

and check this link

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9xk1h71t.aspx